# name of the web service masked

Tags: web, service, subdomain

I have built a web service that requires 3 parameters (`CODE=, DOC_TYPE= and COUNTRY=`).

```
http://188.121.62.21/port_app/fund.a5w?code=LU0045026&DOC_TYPE=ONE&COUNTRY=UK
```

So this is working fine.

The issue is that I would like to use a domain to make the call more "user friendly".

Then the service would be called like:

```
domain.com/?code=LU0045026&DOC_TYPE=ONE&COUNTRY=UK
```

I spoke with Godaddy - where I have the VPS and they say that is not possible.
Any light on this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Buy a domain name, and if your webserver is running Apache, .htaccess mod_rewrite can do what you need. Lots of examples exist for howto rewrite q?uerey=strings into /flat-links/